# Find the differential equation to the closed-loop system

Tags: control-engineering

[image]

[image]

[image]

I know that the closed-loop transfer function is equal to 
Y/Ysp = (P controller * DC motor) /(1+(P controller * DC motor)) then I am struck.  Can anyone give me some hints on how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use the transfer function for this problem, just substitute the known equations in the time domain to get a differential equation for the closed loop. You have

$$ V(t) = K_p e(t) \qquad e = Y_{sp} - Y(t) \qquad \tau_L = 0$$
$$ T \frac{d^2Y(t)}{dt^2} + \frac{dY(t)}{dt} = K V(t) - K_B \tau_L(t)$$

Just insert the first three equations into the fourth and you have your closed loop differential equation.

$$ T \frac{d^2Y(t)}{dt^2} + \frac{dY(t)}{dt} = K K_p (Y_{sp} - Y(t))$$

Rearrange to get into the standard differential equation form with your states on the left-hand-side and your inputs on the right-hand-side:

$$ T \frac{d^2Y(t)}{dt^2} + \frac{dY(t)}{dt} +  K K_p Y(t) = K K_p Y_{sp}$$

Now you can analyze the control system as a simple second-order DE with a constant input.

## Edit: Steady state value

The steady state value can easily be derived from the differential equation. We know that when the system reaches steady state, by definition, $\frac{d^2Y(t)}{dt^2} = 0$ and $\frac{dY(t)}{dt} = 0$. Therefore, substituting those values in the DE and setting $Y(t)=Y_{ss}$:

$$ T \cdot 0 + 0 +  K K_p Y_{ss} = K K_p Y_{sp}$$
$$Y_{ss} = Y_{sp}$$

Comment: Hi . Thanks for your help. Could I check with you now that Ysp has changed (let's said it increase) , how will it affect the response? Is there some guideline to check these response?

Comment: @LearningLaSo if $Y_{sp}$ changes then the system will respond according to the differential equation. I don't know what exactly it is you want to know

Comment: Hmm what I mean how do I check the steady state response based on the second order system equation?

Comment: I can Laplace transform it but I am not sure what the initial condition is.

Comment: @LearningLaSo The steady state value of a linear system is independent of the initial condition